Exam Class - How do you adjust the margins inside a solution box?
I currently want more space between the edges of the solution box and its contents. I know in the exam.cls file that the solution environment uses the MakeFrame environment to "frame" the text. I'm pretty new to LaTeX so I'm not really sure how to adjust the solution environment in order to change the margins of the solution box.
Here's the code:
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}

% use URW Palladio L
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\bfseries\lbrack\thequestion.\rbrack}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{
    \addtolength{\labelwidth}{1em}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{2.5em}
}

\renewcommand{\partlabel}{\textbf{(\thepartno)}}
\pointformat{\bfseries\boldmath(\thepoints)}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}

\begin{document}
\printanswers

\begin{questions}
    \question[10] blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah 
    \begin{solution}
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah
    \end{solution}
\end{questions}

\end{document}



It uses \fboxsep, both to draw the box and to reduce the text width.

@JohnKormylo Changing the length of \fboxsep or \fboxrule doesn't do anything unfortunately. Maybe I'm doing this wrong?

A MWE would have been useful.  The "examframed" environment puts the text into "\fbox" with the settings "\fboxrule=\exam@FrameRule" and "\fboxsep=\exam@FrameSep".  You can use \makeatletter ... \makeatother or \csname exam@FrameRule\endcsname to change the value.

@JohnKormylo Could you provide the code on how to implement this? Sorry, I'm way too new with LaTeX to figure this out. I have edited my initial post to include what I have so far. Thanks!

Normally the @ symbol is not allowed in command names (which is why .sty files use it to prevent accidental duplicate names).
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}

% use URW Palladio L
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\bfseries\lbrack\thequestion.\rbrack}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{
    \addtolength{\labelwidth}{1em}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{2.5em}
}

\renewcommand{\partlabel}{\textbf{(\thepartno)}}
\pointformat{\bfseries\boldmath(\thepoints)}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\exam@FrameSep}{2.5em}% overkill
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\printanswers

\begin{questions}
    \question[10] blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah 
    \begin{solution}
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah
    \end{solution}
\end{questions}

\end{document}


Just out of curiosity, is there also a way to customize the top and bottom margins separately from the left and right within the box?

Not easily.  You could edit/replace the solutionbox environment (search for \vskip 2\fboxsep.  Alternativly you could put each solution into your own environment (based  on minipage) to add additonal margins (possibly setting the default margins to 0pt).
